# MPI recieving arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, mpi

I've got probles with receiving MPI Array. I'm doing something like this:

```
int *b = new int[5];
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    b[i] = i;
                }
                MPI_Send(&b[0], 5, MPI_INT, procesDocelowy, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

this is how I send my array.
Receiving:

```
int *b = new int[5];
            MPI_Recv(&b, 5, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

My problems is that I cant receive arrays which was allocated dynamically. My process hangs just after MPI_recv and I get:

```
job aborted:
rank: node: exit code: message
0: Majster: terminated
1: Majster: terminated
2: Majster: 0xc0000005: process exited without calling finalize
3: Majster: terminated
```

It's quite interesting, because if I initialize my array in static way, I mean

`int b[5];` when receiving and

`int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5};` while sending

everything works fine.

I can't initialize arrays in static way, I have to do this dynamically. Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What _exactly_ is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use `&b` to refer to your array when you call `MPI_Recv()`.  If you use a pointer to a dynamic address, you send the address of the pointer instead of the address of the array.

Comment: I am not good in C++, but even if I have something like this:
`int *b = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    b[i] = i;
}
 MPI_Send(&b[0], 5, MPI_INT, procesDocelowy, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`
    
and 
    
`int *res = new int[5];
MPI_Recv(res, 5, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++) {
 std::cout << res[i] << " ";
}`

My process still doesn't work.

Comment: You're not very good at comments either then :) Please put significant snippets somewhere convenient (pastebin, the question)